# Gradle java-library: api but compileOnly

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, war

rootProject: create a war

subproject foo

```
apply plugin: 'java-libarary
dependencies {
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
}
```

subproject bar

```
apply plugin: 'java-libarary

dependencies {
    compile project(':foo')
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
}
```

Is there a way not to add the same dependencies on the javax.servlet-api twice?
Some compileOnly dependencies of project foo need to be added to project bar, but it should not be in the war. Need a configuration like:

```
apiCompileOnly
```

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking for a way to allow consumers of your library or module to use compileOnly dependencies (without having to redeclare them in the consuming module) there is now compileOnlyApi: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph

This allows will put the dependency of the library on the compile time classpath of any module consuming it:

subproject foo

```
apply plugin: 'java-libarary
dependencies {
    compileOnlyApi group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
}
```

subproject bar now has access to servlet classes when compiling because it imports project foo

```
apply plugin: 'java-libarary

dependencies {
    compile project(':foo')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a configuration like `apiCompileOnly` nothing stopping you from creating one.

```
configurations {
    apiCompileOnly
}
```

or

```
configurations.create('apiCompileOnly')
```

or you can exclude them from the `war`:

```
war {
    rootSpec.exclude('**/javax.servlet-api-*.jar')
}
```

you can include dependencies in each of the subprojects through `subprojects` in the root `build.gradle`

```
subprojects {
    dependencies {
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
    }
}
```

As well you said

> Some compileOnly dependencies of project foo need to be added to project bar, but it should not be in the war.

then in this case the `subprojects` closure is not that handy any more.
you could add the dependencies that are common to all subprojects in there, and the specific ones to the specific projects, but remember about transitives as your `project` dependencies will bring their transitive if you will not disable it like this:

```
compile (project(':foo')){transitive=false}
```

Or you can search for project that you are interested in and add what you need like `@ToYonos` sugested in a nother answer

Comment: apiCompileOnly should be supported in java-libarary and war plugin for auto propagation of dependencies, but excluded from runtime such as war.

Comment: @eastwater im not sure what you mean i could not find anything about `apiCompileOnly` configuration. Where did you found the information about that ?

Comment: it does not exist, but this configuration is useful.

Answer (score 0):

In root project `build.gradle` just add :

```
apply plugin: 'java-libarary'
subprojects {
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
}
```

Or

```
apply plugin: 'java-libarary'
subprojects.findAll { ['foo', 'bar'].contains(it.name) }.each {
    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
}
```